# Transforming array of key value pairs in json to Table in SQL Server

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table where one column is the id of some executed code and the other column is an array of key value pairs of the name of the parameters passed and the values
Formatted like this

```
executionId|params                                                           |

200001     |[{"key":"name","value":"john"},{"key":"surname","value":"smith"}]|
```

where the amount of parameters passed is arbitrary and i want to output it formatted as a table.

I tried with this query

```sql
SELECT 
   t.executionId,
   j.*
FROM #tmpTransac t
CROSS APPLY (
   SELECT * 
   FROM OPENJSON(t.[params])
   ) j
```

But the output i get is this

```
executionId|key|value
1992013     0   {"key":"name","value":"john"}
1992013     1   {"key":"surname","value":"smith"}
```

and i expected something like

```
executionId| name |surname
1992013    | john |smith
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion uses `OPENJSON` including a `WITH` clause and `PIVOT`

--A *mockup table*

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(executionId INT,params NVARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES(200001,'[{"key":"name","value":"john"},{"key":"surname","value":"smith"}]');
```

-the query

```
SELECT p.*
FROM
(
    SELECT t.executionId
          ,A.[key] AS ParamKey
          ,A.[value] AS ParamValue
    FROM @tbl t
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(t.params) WITH([key] NVARCHAR(MAX),[value] NVARCHAR(MAX)) A
) t
PIVOT(MAX(ParamValue) FOR ParamKey IN([Name],Surname)) p;
```

The idea in short:

It is a bit bewildering, that the JSON elements carry the same names as the columns returned by `OPENJSON`. but the `WITH` clause will look for these **names within the JSON**, so this will return a list like

```
name       john
surname    smith
```

To get this *side-by-side* you can use either `PIVOT` or *conditional aggregation*-

Answer (score 0):

You need to pivot out your data, as it's in 2 separate JSON strings inside your larger value:

```
SELECT V.executionId,
       MAX(CASE N.[key] WHEN 'name' THEN N.[value] END) AS [name],
       MAX(CASE N.[key] WHEN 'surname' THEN N.[value] END) AS [surname]
FROM (VALUES(200001,'[{"key":"name","value":"john"},{"key":"surname","value":"smith"}]'))V(executionId, params)
     CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(V.params) OJ
     CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(OJ.[value]) 
                 WITH ([key] varchar(50) '$.key',
                       [value] varchar(100) '$.value') N
GROUP BY V.executionId;
```